# A site to search Kosher Symbols by characteristics?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, internet, hechsher-certification, symbols-symbology

Several years ago, I found a website that let me search and sort Kosher symbols by look and other characteristics. It seemed like each symbol was tagged with its distinctive features. This was very useful when trying to find information on the Kosher agency when all you had was the symbol.

For example, if one was trying to find more information about a Kosher symbol that had a Magen David, one could just look at all the symbols that had a Magen David.

There are guides that list kosher symbols, such as [this one](http://www.kashrusmagazine.com/) (their 2012 print edition has 1127 symbols and [the online edition from 2007](http://www.kashrusmagazine.com/ksg/Old%20and%20deleted/ksg_index.html) has 867 symbols), but they are not searchable by symbol, only location.

I can't find the site now (maybe it no longer exists). Does anyone know of this site or a suitable replacement?

Comment: I remember that site too and have searched for it in vain in the past. If I recall correctly, it was related to someone's academic research in image recognition.

Comment: @IsaacMoses: is the one in my answer the one you were thinking of?

Comment: I think so; thanks! Unfortunately, it looks like it relies on a lot of manual maintenance.

Comment: Where do you live?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the site I was thinking of, anyone know of any others?

http://www.hechshers.info/shapes/index.htm

Comment: Dead link, shame

Answer (score 2):

Let me add this useful info:

There is also a good website to search on Kosher symbols of the  kosher  certification agencies.

Kosher Register http://kosherregister.com has a search engine -

SEARCH by Certification Logo - http://www.kosherregister.com/certifingOrg/kosher-certification-symbol-and-trademark.htm

If you are looking for a certifying logo with a star then just type in "Star" on the search box and then search results will come up on the [kosher](http://kosherregister.com) agencies with the Star Logo.

Aside from the kosher symbols, you can also search there by Certification Name, the personnel affiliated with the agency as well as the locations of the agencies

Comment: It *seems* to search by name and other terms, not shape. E.g., I searched for `star` and it found the Star-K but not the Young Israel's dairy-star thingy; I searched for `moon` and it didn't find the 'half-moon K'.

Comment: Half moon k is defunct.

Comment: @msh210 yes you are right and I stand corrected. The search options for the logos is currently under development but fortunately you can now search for any kosher certification organization by location, certification name and by personnel. If you want to add the search box to your site, you can now request by sending an email to info@kosherregister.com

Comment: @msh210, should this answer be deleted? The links are defunct