# Is Cup-K reliable?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

I've recently seen a hashgacha around NYC called Cup-K or CupK. However, I have been able to find precious little about it and what I have found seems mostly to consist of unsubstiatable rumours. Does anyone have any knowledge of the reliability of this hashgacha? FWIW, it's the one formerly used by the famous Second Avenue Deli and  currently certifying famous vegan restaurant Buddha Bodai.

[image: Cup-K image]

Comment: http://www.2ndavedeli.com/about/kosher-certification/ cum http://forward.com/news/israel/12725/msh210-01325/ fwiw.

Comment: http://www.thanksaglatt.com/hechsher-directory/hechsher-directory/ says Stringency: Conservative (Restaurants open on Shabbat)

Comment: @msh210, there's a reliable hashgacha in Boston which permits [at least some of] its restaurants to be open on Shabbat. However, one restaurant in particular, while it is known to have reliable certification, does not advertise its hashgacha, which is recognised on http://www.kashrut.com/agencies/ , whereas Cup-K is not.

Comment: try using http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16008/759

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt, I don't know why you're telling me this. My comment was aimed at providing you or other potential answerers with an avenue of research toward answering your question. Yours seems to be aimed at... disagreeing with the _Forward_, perhaps?

Comment: Hi @NoachMiFrankfurt. It looks like the last comment came in while I was typing my answer. If you would, ponder through it. I'm not sure if you had already made up your mind, as your question borders between an info question and an opinion question. If my answer is completely unuseful, inform me. I don't like occupying unwanted space, here.

Comment: Great question. Can't provide any kind of substantial answer, but I will say that "cup K" is the go-to example of a "bad hechsher" in my community

Comment: http://www.hashkafah.com/index.php?/topic/56158-is-this-a-reliable-hechsher/?p=1209705 and http://www.hashkafah.com/index.php?/topic/56158-is-this-a-reliable-hechsher/?p=1210320

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/legaladvice/comments/6rf62t/misleading_kosher_vegan_restaurant/

Comment: For what it's worth, 2nd Ave Deli is now under the IKC.

Comment: @TheAsh, I'm aware. It's a marked improvement, but I don't think I'll eat there since I don't know what R' Schwartz holds for fleischig places

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I am unaware of anyone who holds of IKC either, except for ice cream and the like. But he is far more transparent, so it's a plus. Meat is still not glatt, and store is still sold on Shabbos.

Comment: They are not reliable. A quick visit to the Buddha bodai website shows they operate on shabbos. Additionally this website is not for practical psak din questions.

Comment: @Dude, my local va'ad, the KVH, has a cholov-Yisroel hechshered restaurant which, due to non-Jewish ownership, is open on Shabbat. I don't know of anyone notable in the community who doesn't hold of there, but eats at restaurants

Comment: Excellent thread: https://disqus.com/home/discussion/thanksaglatt/rabbi_israel_mayer_steinberg_of_vaad_harabonim_lemeshmeret_hakashrut/oldest/

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt is the food being cooked on shabbos? Is everything being paid for in advance as a reservation?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt what restaurant?

Comment: This list by a Modern Orthodox congregation explicitly lists it as an unacceptable hechsher: https://brofjo.tripod.com/kosher.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems to beg two things - Is it reliable, as well as some info about the hashgacha.
As for info, I located [this article](http://www.thanksaglatt.com/news/rabbi-israel-mayer-steinberg-of-vaad-harabonim-lemeshmeret-hakashrut/) about the supervising rabbi, Rabbi Israel Mayer Steinberg of Vaad Harabonim Lemeshmeret Hakashrut, as well as [this article](http://forward.com/news/israel/12725/2nd-ave-deli-cooks-up-controversy-01325/) that focuses a bit more specifically on the 2nd Ave. Deli.

The controversy, as I understand it, relates to whether a place that is open on Shabbat can be considered kosher?

Rabbi Steinberg states that the 2nd Ave. Deli has been sold to a non-Jew on Shabbat, thus, he claims that this would avoid the concern for those that won't eat in a place run by a non Shabbat observant Jew. I can't state how well this rule works both in general as well as regarding the 2nd Ave. Deli. They may have other specific kashrut problems, in general, that are unrelated to the Shabbat issue.

As for another place called "Littlelads", which no longer exists, that place was vegan. I had eaten there several times, unaware that there was a Shomer-Shabbat and mashgiach temidi issue. So, obviously, my actions and opinion, on this place are based on ignorance.

In general, I am uncertain if a place being Shomer Shabbat is an absolute requirement for a place to be kosher. I know that most certifying agencies won't certify such a place. We know that a large piece of kosher certification in the U.S. is political. Essentially, Rabbi Steinberg is using a less-favored opinion that states that a place can remain open on Shabbat and still remain kosher because it's not Jewishly owned on Shabbat.

What I will try to research further is if Rabbi Steinberg certifies places that are owned by non-Shomer-Shabbat Jews that DON'T sell their store. That adds another piece to the "puzzle". However, even in this case, I'm not sure if being non-shomer-Shabbat would invalidate the actual kashrut of a restaurant assuming that the food is kosher, and, if they had a mashgiach temidi, which even many certified establishments don't have.

In short, we have a interesting vagueness...

Comment: As I commented in the thread below my OP, there is a well-known and reliable restaurant in Boston which has such a heter in its hashgacha. I know that most members of the Cambridge Orthodox community will eat food catered from either their milchig or their fleischig kitchen.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt You mention that the "Cambridge Orthodox community will eat food catered from either their milchig or their fleischig kitchen". Is its hechsher Cup-K or another one? I'm unclear. If it's a different hechesher that's doing the same idea as Cup-K, then why arte you hesitant to rely on Cup-K? FWIW, there were a number of Orthodox people I knew that ate at Littlelads (see above). Perhaps, they were more trusting because it was vegan vs. trusting 2nd Ave. Deli. However, I think in case of 2nd Ave. Deli, they may have been using Hebrew National & maybe other probs w/ meat was issue

Comment: it's under the Badatz of Boston, which is listed in Kashrut.com's list. See http://kosher.mit.edu/kosher-boston/ for a list of local kosher places near me (the Cywiak hashgacha is also known as Badatz and is AFAIK also under the control of R' Yitzchok Aharon Korff of Zhvil)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt OK. So that leads to the 2nd route. Badat'z Boston gives a hechsher to a place that's open on Shabbat. How is what Rav Steinberg doing different? (BTW, the YU cafeteria is open on Shabbat, though they don't collect money. How is that different?)

Comment: I have heard a rumour that his standards for carcasses are significantly more lenient than even Triangle K, although without any examples to back it up.

Comment: DanF, I just saw online that Tevere, on the Upper East Side is open on Shabbat. They are under the OU, according to their website.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt, Tevere is open on Saturdays, [one hour after Sunset](http://www.teverenyc.com/current/faq.php).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41213/mashgiach-and-a-restaurant-staying-open-on-shabbos

Answer (score 4):

[Cup-K](https://web.archive.org/web/20200725223557/http://www.thanksaglatt.com/hechsher-directory/hechsher-directory/#Cup-K) shows the citation below. Note the Stringency line (**Conservative**) on the hechsher listing. This would raise a question in my mind.

One  question would be what is done on Shabat and could the non-Jew bring in food then to cook. Is it like a franchise that can only use franchise provided food (that is always under supervision) like Carvel or certain Yogurt places or like a regular restaurant.

> Cup-K
>
> Under the supervision of Rabbi Israel Mayer Steinberg of Vaad
> Harabonim Lameshmeret Hakashrut.
>
> Stringency: Conservative (Restaurants open on Shabbat)
>
> Restaurants:
>
> ```
> Bhojan – New York City
> Loving Hut – New York City (Penn Station)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I happened to just now pass by this place called Eden kosher in Yonkers. Prominently displayed in their window is a kosher certificate from cup k. Intrigued I walked into the place and walked right out after seeing the Hebrew National cold cuts. I have no vendetta against anyone and I'm not telling anyone what to do I'm just a simple frum guy and nobody's rabbi, but this certification fails the standards of anybody who actually bothers to verify a hechsher.

Comment: Hebrew National is under the certification of Triangle-K http://www.hebrewnational.com/triangle-k-kosher-certified Maybe you should try bothering to verify things instead of assuming that certain brands aren't Kosher.

Comment: @DoubleAA, many don't consider Triangle K reliable.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Indeed, but it doesn't "fail[] the standards of anybody who actually bothers to verify a hechsher"

Answer (score 2):

An issue that looms large in my mind is the choice of a hechsher name that sounds so much like another, very trusted hechsher.  Call up a restaurant and ask who supervises them.  If the answer is "Cup K" you might well think they said kof-k.

Also, the Cup-K is NOT included in any O list of accepted hechsherim that I have seen, such as: 
http://www.ozny.org/kosher

http://www.crcweb.org/agency_list.php

Organizations that serve their communities by compiling lists of restaurants with acceptable hechshers try to create complete lists. It might be that one organization might miss an acceptable restaurant or hechsher, but it is highly unlikely that a pattern of omission arose by chance. In short, that pattern is more than an "unsubstantiated rumor".

Comment: I don't see how this qualifies as "knowledge of the reliability of this hashgacha".

Comment: I guess that means they also don't have "knowledge of the reliability of this hashgacha".

Comment: @DoubleAA  What is likely is that they have knowledge of the person giving this hashgacha and do not approve of his standards.

Comment: @YehudaW It's certainly possible. You of course have no way of knowing. Perhaps you should be just as careful as they are about mistakenly spreading incorrect info about others.

Comment: @DoubleAA  Statements by reliable organizations are indications that the low respect for the Cup-K is not an "unsubstiatable rumour" which is the wording of the question.  Likewise the duplicitous choice of the hechsher name is relevant as well.

Comment: "the duplicitous choice of the hechsher name is relevant as well" This is totally false and frankly absurd. It's one of the most absurd things I've ever read on this website. Literally.

Comment: "Statements by reliable organizations" There _are no statements_ about the cup k by reliable organizations. You don't seem to understand that.

Comment: @DoubleAA  You are missing the big picture.  The omission of Cup-K is shouting the opinion of these organizations.  An omission is as clear a statement as these organizations will make publicly about a questionable hechsher.  It is naive to expect such organizations to detail what they see as shortcomings in an omitted hechsher.

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you think a will that says, I leave all my worldly belongings to my oldest and youngest daughters is not saying something about the middle daughter(s)?

Comment: "It is naive to expect such organizations to detail what they see as shortcomings in an omitted hechsher." Of course. It's also naive to think they have investigated every organization. Your arguments about wills etc are meaningless as they miss the point.

Comment: It's amazing how much effort Hashgachas can go through to not imply that anyone not on their list is treif, and still we get people like you spreading rumors and lashon hara all over the internets.

Comment: It is not naive to think that organizations that serve their communities by compiling lists of restaurants with acceptable hechchers have tried to create complete lists.  It might be that one organization might miss an acceptable restaurant or hechsher, but it is highly unlikely that a pattern of omission arose by chance.

Comment: I doesn't have to be chance. There are other reasons besides chance. For instance, the Hekhsher could be tiny. It wouldn't be odd that the Vaad of New Zealand's symbol didn't make it on the radar of any of the US Hekhsherim. Your logic is embarrassing. At least no one will take this answer seriously after reading the nonsense about name similarity.

Comment: There are not that many restaurants in NYC with what the O community considers a reliable hechsher.  So restaurants with an acceptable hechsher would tend to get on compiled lists.  (Cup-K supervises many restaurants in NYC., so is not a minor player.) A hechsher that is not found in NYC (your Australian hechsher) is not relevant to the purpose of such lists.  Further, the name similarity is not nonsense. It is a serious matter of misleading the consumer.  There is established halacha about misleading the consumer in such ways.

Comment: "The omission of Cup-K is shouting the opinion of these organizations. An omission is as clear a statement as these organizations will make publicly about a questionable hechsher." (from your comment). This is incorrect, as there are some agencies that aren't on [the cRc list](http://www.crcweb.org/agency_list.php) but that cRc approves of (as noted in its Twitter posts). "Organizations that serve their communities by compiling lists of restaurants with acceptable hechchers try to create complete lists." (from your answer). This is also false, as the cRc doesn't update its list when it tweets.

Comment: @msh210  I was referring to local shuls that compile lists of eating establishments with a hechsher that reflects community standards.  There are a number of local O shuls that do that for restaurants in the NYC area. Cup-K is not on any of them, as far as I have seen.

Comment: I admire those that are scrupulous about eating only kosher food. We should be equally scrupulous not to slander establishments that are kosher but rely on different halachic opinions

Comment: @DoubleAA, funnily enough, I've heard that when the Kof-K made a statement about Cup-K, after the issue was brought to their attention, R' Steinberg sued them in US court and put a gag order on them to avoid them ever mentioning it again (I don't have the court filing info, so no source offhand)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt court filings by the Cup K are under Yoel Steinberg the son.

Comment: This shul explicitly lists it as unaceptable: https://brofjo.tripod.com/kosher.pdf